# EditText's cursor position

Tags: android

Assuming, that a user has written some text into an **EditText** and thereafter touched somewhere else on the screen, which caused the cursor position to change: How can one determine the new cursor position?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simple version:

```
myEditText.getSelectionStart();
```

If you want to react on an event you may try

```
myEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        // view is myEditText here
    }
});
```

`event` allows to distinguish between presses and releases.

`EditText` also has a `setOnClickListener()` that might be worth to look at.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention `onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd)` where selEnd equals selStart if the position changed.

Comment: To clarify: onSelectionChanged() must be overridden in EditText subclasses to be useful.  OnTouch events only happen when the user literally touches the screen.  OnClick events can be fired when the user touches the screen or via certain physical inputs, e.g. D-pad center, trackball click, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Best and safe way is using **TextWatcher**

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                int cursorIndex = start + 1;
        }
```

Comment: User can move the cursor around without changing the text. This approach is useless over there.