# Keep focus on TextView after notifyDatasetChanged() was called on custom listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a listview adapter that when I modify my TextView, I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on `addTextChangeListener()` method. But my TextView lose the focus.
How I can keep the focus, overriding the `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

I do that but didn't work

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged(){
    TextView txtCurrentFocus = (TextView) getCurrentFocus();
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    txtCurrentFocus.requestFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `ListView` class and override `requestLayout()` method. That method is called, when `ListView` finish update and steal focus. So, at the end of this methos you can return focus to your `TextView`.

```
public class ExampleListView extends ListView {

    private ListViewListener mListener;

    public ExampleListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExampleListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExampleListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void requestLayout() {
        super.requestLayout();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onChangeFinished();
        }
    }

    public void setListener(ListViewListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface ListViewListener {
        void onChangeFinished();
    }
}
```

and set listener to this `ListView`

```
ExampleListView listView = (ExampleListView) view.findViewById(R.id.practice_exercises_list);
listView.setListener(new ExampleListView.ListViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChangeFinished() {
                txtCurrentFocus.requestFocus();
            }
        });
```

Comment: thats nice and all, but when doing this, i loose the position of the focus in an editText. Any advice how i could solve this problem?

Comment: @glace You can remember text position by using [TextWatcher as suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15030172/1219012]) and restore that position using [setSelection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035107/how-to-set-cursor-position-in-edittext)

Comment: How can i know on which EditText i shall use this when generated dynamically. Pls don't tell me that i have to use one TextWatcher for each EditText. It must be possible to use one TextWatcer for multiple EditTexts right? Otherwise i will need ~30 plus TextWatchers -.-

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with `EditText` and `RecyclerView` 
using this line of code, for my `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` solved the problem.

```
 adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
```